# How to access the updated state in the body of a function that has already called setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm currently coding a function to save the `blogPost` object into a `document` in my Firestore database.

The intended routine should be:

- Click on SAVE button and call the `savePost()` function
- The `savePost()` function should call the `uploadImagesAndGetURL()` function because the images of the `blogPost` should be uploaded to Firebase Storage before I save their `src` URL to the Firestore. (in my real case the image upload is `async` and I `await` for it to complete, but I don't think it hurts the example here).
- The `uploadImagesAndGetURL()` should upload the images and store the returned `urls` for each one in their respective `src` property, inside the `elements` array of the `state`.
- It does that by running a `forEach()` on the `elements` array and calling `setState()` (setBlogPost) to update state with the new URL's received from the storage.
- The `saveToFirestore()` function will then be called and should be able to access the most recent state to be able to save the `blogPost` object along with the image `src's` to the database.

**QUESTION**

My problem is that while I'm running the `savePost()` function the component is being re-rendered 3 times in this case (for 3 images), because the `uploadImagesAndGetURL()` is calling `setBlogPost()` 3 times. One for each image. And when I reach the `saveToFirestore()` function and I log the `blogPost` state, you can see that only the first image `src` has changed.

Am I doing it right? How can I improve this routine to make sure everything has been updated before I `saveToFirestore()`?

**NOTE:** One way to do it would be to skip the state update and pass the returned URLs straight to the `saveToFirestore()` function without ever storing them on the state. But, what is the appropriate pattern in this situation?

**Log from the `saveToFirestore()` function:**

```
{
  "title": "This is the title",
  "body": "Click on the button to upload this post",
  "elements": [
    {
      "type": "image",
      "src": "source0"
    },
    {
      "type": "image",
      "src": null
    },
    {
      "type": "image",
      "src": null
    }
  ]
}
```

**SNIPPET BELOW**

```js
function App() {
  console.log('Rendering App...');
  const [blogPost,setBlogPost] = React.useState({
    title: 'This is the title',
    body: 'Click on the button to upload this post',
    elements: [
      { type: 'image',
        src: null 
      },
      { type: 'image',
        src: null
      },
      { type: 'image',
        src: null 
      }
    ]
  });

  function savePost() {
    console.log('Inside savePost');
    uploadImagesAndGetURL();
    saveToFirestore();
  }
  
  function uploadImagesAndGetURL() {
    console.log('Inside uploadImages');
    blogPost.elements.forEach((item,index) => {
      console.log('Inside uploadImages - forEach');
      setBlogPost((prevState)=>{
        const aux = Array.from(prevState.elements);
        aux[index].src = 'source' + index;
        return({
          ...prevState,
          elements: aux
        });
      });
    });
  }
  
  function saveToFirestore() {
    console.log('Inside saveToFirestore');
    console.log('Will save the following blogPost to Firestore');
    console.log(blogPost);
  }

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>{blogPost.title}</div>
      <div>{blogPost.body}</div>
      <div>Image 1 src: {blogPost.elements[0].src}</div>
      <div>Image 2 src: {blogPost.elements[1].src}</div>
      <div>Image 3 src: {blogPost.elements[2].src}</div>
      <button onClick={savePost}>Save Post</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Why not use the effect hook to trigger saveToFirestore?

Comment: And the effect would run based on what? Since I have multiple `setState()` calls? I could create a state flag with a `hasUploaded` boolean and run the effect based on that. But even if I update this boolean after all the `setState` for the `src`, can I be sure of the order of those setState calls and that `hasUploaded` will be the last one applied?

Comment: React batches calls to `setState` since it is happening in an event handler, so the effect hook will only run once after the whole update.

Comment: @Remeus will the batching work even if the `setState` calls are one level deeper inside the event handler? Like in my case the handler is `savePost` and it calls `uploadImagesAndGetURL` and then it calls the `setState`?

Comment: As long as React can know for sure when all the state changes will be made (no async for instance), it should yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the save logic within the `useEffect` hook as you are changing the blog state, it'd trigger the effect to run.

Follow along on [image: Edit so.answer.56544887]

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  console.log("Rendering App...");
  const [blogPost, setBlogPost] = React.useState({
    title: "This is the title",
    body: "Click on the button to upload this post",
    elements: [
      { type: "image", src: null },
      { type: "image", src: null },
      { type: "image", src: null }
    ]
  });

  function savePost() {
    console.log("Inside savePost");
    uploadImagesAndGetURL();
    // saveToFirestore();
  }

  function uploadImagesAndGetURL() {
    console.log("Inside uploadImages");
    const elements = blogPost.elements.map((_, index) => ({
      type: "image",
      src: `source${index}`
    }));
    setBlogPost(previousPost => ({ ...previousPost, elements }));
  }

  // function uploadImagesAndGetURL() {
  //   console.log("Inside uploadImages");
  //   blogPost.elements.forEach((item, index) => {
  //     console.log("Inside uploadImages - forEach");
  //     setBlogPost(prevState => {
  //       const aux = Array.from(prevState.elements);
  //       aux[index].src = "source" + index;
  //       return {
  //         ...prevState,
  //         elements: aux
  //       };
  //     });
  //   });
  // }

  useEffect(() => {
    function saveToFirestore() {
      console.log("Inside saveToFirestore");
      console.log("Will save the following blogPost to Firestore");
      console.log(blogPost);
    }
    saveToFirestore();
  }, [blogPost]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>{blogPost.title}</div>
      <div>{blogPost.body}</div>
      <div>Image 1 src: {blogPost.elements[0].src}</div>
      <div>Image 2 src: {blogPost.elements[1].src}</div>
      <div>Image 3 src: {blogPost.elements[2].src}</div>
      <button onClick={savePost}>Save Post</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

> the uploadImagesAndGetURL() is calling setBlogPost() 3 times.

And also I'd actually get the list of URLs and set the `elements` property in one go to prevent re-render 3 times.

Comment: This is a good solution, but in my real case scenario the `blogPost` changes for other reasons too. See the comment on the question that I wrote.

Comment: Would it be possible to generate a new instance of `blogPost` inside `uploadImagesAndGetURL`, pass it to both `setBlogPost`& `saveToFireStore`? It'd rid the need to call `useEffect` and shows that `saveToFireStore` depends on the blog post explicitly.

Comment: Good idea! I'll try that!